# binary to decimal converter using while loops

Tags: python

I am unable to multiply 2 with the correct power when calculating the decimal equivalent

```
b=str(input("Enter binary number here "))
a=1
c=1
for i in (b):
    while i==0:
        a=0
    while i==1:
        c=1*(2**b(i))
print(c+a)
```

I am only getting 2 as the output

Comment: `b = '101101'; x = int( b, 2); print(x); --> 45`

Comment: In your code, when is `i` ever equal to `0` or `1`?  (it's not)  Also, notice that you're using `while` loops and if condition was ever true, they'd never end because the condition would never change (the stuff inside the loop isn't doing anything to affect the condition).  Finally, what is `b(i)` supposed to be?  I believe you might not understand what `for i in b` is giving you... it'll get you each character you typed from the `input()` line--no numbers involved. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a bit wrong here (not uncommon for folks getting started), so I'm going to explain a little about what's wrong first.  There are comments inline with your code below:

```
b=str(input("Enter binary number here "))

a=1
c=1

# No need for parens here, it doesn't add anything.
for i in (b):
    # Two issues: i is never 0 (the integer).
    # It could be '0' (a string containing the ASCII digit 0).
    # Also, even if you fix the conditional (i == '0'), the loop
    # would never end because we do nothing to change i inside
    # the loop.
    while i==0:
        a=0

    # Similar problem.  i can never be the integer 1 here, and
    # the loop condition is still a problem.  You probably
    # really wanted 'if' instead.
    while i==1:
        # Not entirely sure what you were going for here.  It
        # looked like you got the idea that i would be 0 or 1
        # (and now you know it's actually '0' or '1'), but
        # then you do: b(i), which I can't figure out.  I think
        # you were trying to do something like 2**i, where i is
        # the position of the digit (which it's not).
        #
        # Either way, it's not doing what you expect.  The
        # syntax: name(arg) is really a function call.  So
        # you're trying to call your string with the current
        # digit, which Python cannot do and will throw an
        # exception.
        c=1*(2**b(i))

# In the end, you're not really adding things up as you go
# along, so the end result will never actually be the value.
print(c+a)
```

Now that we know what's wrong, we have some options.  For the examples, we'll assume `b` is `"1011"`, since it's easy to see when we're wrong.  If the left-most digit is the most significant then the value should be `11`.  If the right-most digit is significant then the value would be 13.

#### Option 1

```
val = 0
for digit in b:
    # Shift val and prepare for the new digit.  Shifting means
    # moving it one binary position.  This can be done by using
    # the shift operator (<<) or by simply multiplying by 2.
    # Any of the following statements would work:
    #    val = val * 2
    #    val *= 2  (shorthand for the above)
    #    val = val << 1 (shift left by 1)
    #    val <<= 1  (shorthand for the above)
    val <<= 1
    if digit == '1':
        # When the digit is a '1', we bitwise OR in the bit.
        # You could also say:
        #     val = val + 1
        #     val += 1
        #     val = val | 1
        #     val |= 1
        val |= 1

print(val)
# 11
```

#### Option 2 (your approach)

```
val = 0
for i, digit in enumerate(b):
   # Here i will count up as we iterate through the digits, and
   # digit will have the actual string digit.
   #
   # This will compute something unexpected though since it
   # treats later digits as more significant (which is
   # different than the way we write them).
   if digit == '1':
       val += 2**i

print(val)
# 13
```

#### Option 3 (your approach, reversed)

```
val = 0
for i, digit in enumerate(reversed(b)):
   # Here i will count up as we iterate through the digits.
   # This will compute the value the way you expect, treating
   # rightmost digits as less significant.  This works because
   # we reversed the string before computing the answer.
   if digit == '1':
       val += 2**i

print(val)
# 11
```

Personally, I like Option 1 best as it's succinct, easy to read, and easy to understand what is happening.

Comment: If we were to do it like this :

Comment: My assignment is to do this code using nested loops actually and i have just started so i am having a bit of problem understanding the shift operator and the "enumerate" function. I tried it using this :    bin=(input("Enter binary number here"))
    val=0
    n=len(bin)
    for i in range(n,0,-1):
        for j in digit(bin):
            if j==1:
                val+=j*(i**2)
    print(val)

Comment: bin=(input("Enter binary number here"))
val=0
n=len(bin)
for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
    print(i)
    for digit in (bin):
        if digit==1:
            val+=digit*(i**2)
print(val)
    why does this not work

Comment: @SatwikKumar In Python, `for` is actually a "for each" style loop.  Meaning it doesn't count a range of numbers, but give you each item in a container instead.  When you wrap your string in [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), instead of just getting a letter, you get both an index and a letter.  The best way to describe `<< n` (shifting left by n) is that it's the same as multiplying by `2**n`.

Comment: @SatwikKumar it doesn't work because the string digit '1' is not the same as the integer 1.  Try it in the interpreter: `1 == '1'` will give you `False`.  Python does *not* automatically convert strings that looks like numbers to integers.  In the code above, I assume you got `0` as the answer.  The reason for that is that `digit == 1` should be `digit == '1'` (note the quotes in the latter, those are important).  If your goal is to do this as nested loops, then you need to think a little more about how to accomplish that.  Hint: can you convert multiplication by 2**i to a loop?

Comment: I got it,  much appreciated ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Checking if the binary digit is either `0` or `1` is not required as multiplying by 0 will return 0 anyway.

```py
bin_no = input('Enter a binary number: ')  # input returns the input as str by default
base = 2
place_val = 0
decimal = 0

for digit in bin_no[::-1]:  # traverse the digits in a reversed way
    decimal += int(digit) * base**place_val
    place_val += 1

print(f'Decimal of {bin_no} is {decimal}')
```

Output:

```
Enter a binary number: 101101
Decimal of 101101 is 45
```

Or you can use `int` to convert a binary number to a decimal number.

```py
b = '101101'
x = int(b, 2)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
45
```